# Save file size of clip made with MoviePy

Tags: python, moviepy

Is there any way to know how big the file will be from writing that clip to a videofile? For example

```
from moviepy.editor import *
clip = VideoFileClip('video.mp4')
#Want to know how big clip is
clip.write_videofile('out.mp4')
```

Using `sys.getsizeof(clip)` doesn't work for this. Is there any way to know or estimate this filesize before writing it?

Comment: There's nothing built-in to moviepy to do this. It might be possible to calculate it (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546345/how-to-calculate-ffmpeg-output-file-size might help), but if its being compressed to .mp4, that would affect it, so it might be very hard to calculate.